# How would i get a list of all files and folders in a directory in java

Tags: java, file

I was trying to write a methods to get all directories and files in a directory and finally decided to give up and ask here.

I know this has been asked a few times and has been answered but this is a little harder.

I did get this code

```
    public static void listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files)
    {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);

        // get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                files.add(file);
            } else if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
            }


        }
        System.out.println(files);
    }
```

and it helped a lot but i need it to also give the directory it was in ei.

```
C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Folder\\Folder1\\a.txt
C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Folder\\Folder1\\b.txt

C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Folder\\Folder2\\c.txt
```

My first code:

```
public class FileTransfer
{
    private final static File testFileFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Melaia\\Desktop\\Send\\");
    private static File[] filesInFolder;

    private static String[] listOfFilesInFolder;

    private static int noOfFilesInFolder, k = 0;

    public static void startupFileSend()
    {


        filesInFolder = testFileFolder.listFiles();
        noOfFilesInFolder = (filesInFolder.length);



        for(int zzz = 0; zzz <= noOfFilesInFolder; zzz++)
        {



            if(filesInFolder[k].isDirectory())
            {
                File[] file1 = filesInFolder[k].listFiles();

                listOfFilesInFolder[k] = file1[k].getName() + ";";
            }
            else
            {
                listOfFilesInFolder[k] = filesInFolder[k].getName();
            }

            System.out.println(listOfFilesInFolder[k]);

        }


    }
}
```

but that gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Com.org.FileTransfer.startupFileSend(FileTransfer.java:32)
    at Com.org.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Please can someone give me any advice on this.

Thanks Luke.

Comment: I 90% sure it, haven't updated to java 8 yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) initialize this one `listOfFilesInFolder` like this

`listOfFilesInFolder = new String[noOfFilesInFolder]`

2) Not sure if this is the only problem but change

`zzz <= noOfFilesInFolder`

to

`zzz < noOfFilesInFolder`

3) Also, you never change the `k` variable, not sure if that's intended.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that makes it run once more than i need it to, the problem has something to do with my String array but i cannot for the life of me find it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, i don't know how i missed that. thanks so much.

Comment: Also sorry but i also would like to ask 1 more small question its not very big so i don't think its worth posting a new question but when i first created my account i got a few messages saying a few restrictions have been removed for reputation increse but they dont work nor do i have any reputation. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java 7, don't bother and use a [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html).

Create a class, even anonymous, to manage all files in your directory, the `Files.walkFileTree()` method will walk the file for you and execute the code you have put in the visitor on the different events.

You may also extend `SimpleFileVisitor` instead. You can see two examples of visitors (one for recursive copy, another for recursive deletion) [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/working-with-java-7-file-api-recursive.html).

Since you seem to want to upload, you'll probably want also to use `Files.copy()`, which can take a source path and send its content to an `OutputStream`.